# Update query output clause values into another table from within merge query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my simple merge query. If no match found in USER profile table, it will insert new records for PUB, PVT. If exist it will update statuses. Now I want to use output clause to get updated value and move into history table.

But I am getting syntax error

> A MERGE statement must be terminated by a semi-colon (;)
> just before **WHEN NOT MATCHED**.

```
MERGE [dbo].[USER_PROFILE] AS target
USING (
    VALUES (130, 'PUB'), (130, 'PVT')
) AS source(UserId, PROFILE)
ON target.UserId = source.UserId AND PROFILE = PROFILE
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET 
            Verified = 1,
            Created = 1
        OUTPUT 
            INSERTED.UserId, 
            INSERTED.Verified, 
            INSERTED. Created, 
  INTO [history].[USER_PROFILE] (UserId, Verified, Created)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (
            UserId, Profile,Verified, Created
        )
        VALUES (
            source.UserId, source.Profile,0,0
        )
        OUTPUT 
            INSERTED.UserId, 
            INSERTED.Profile, 
            INSERTED.Verified, 
            INSERTED.Created, 
        INTO [history].[Profile] (UserId, Profile, Created, Verified);
```

Comment: As per the documentation, a merge statement can only have a single `output` clause at the end. Not one per match/not match.

Comment: thank you @DaleK. it worked. But I get new error.
Error: Cannot insert rows in a temporal history table 'CMD.USERDATA.history.Profile'.
Any idea?

Comment: That's a very different question, ask a new one

Comment: You don't `output` into a Temporal history table. The whole point of Temporal tables is it does that for you.

Comment: ah makes sense!! sorry I got it now! @Xedni thank you

Answer (score 0):

A `MERGE` can only have a single `OUTPUT` clause, and it must go at the end. You would have seen this if you would [consult the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#syntax).

```sql
MERGE dbo.USER_PROFILE AS target
USING (VALUES
    (130, 'PUB'),
    (130, 'PVT')
) AS source (UserId, PROFILE)
ON target.UserId = source.UserId AND source.PROFILE = target.PROFILE
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET 
            Verified = 1,
            Created = 1
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (
            UserId, Profile, Verified, Created
        )
        VALUES (
            source.UserId, source.Profile, 0, 0
        )
    OUTPUT 
        INSERTED.UserId, 
        INSERTED.Profile, 
        INSERTED.Verified, 
        INSERTED.Created, 
    INTO history.Profile
        (UserId, Profile, Created, Verified);
```

It's also clear from your comments that this output table is a history table of a temporal table. You don't insert into that directly, the system does it for you.